# How to make unique key with values in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am using laravel framework to develop API's. i was stuck at one point i have one array with duplicate keys and random values like following

```
array:35 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "Contact Info" => 75
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    "Contact Info" => 76
  ]
  2 => array:1 [
    "Contact Info" => 77
  ]
  3 => array:1 [
    "Contact Info" => 78
  ]
  4 => array:1 [
    "Contact Info" => 79
  ]

  12 => array:1 [
    "Contact Info" => 596
  ]
  13 => array:1 [
    "Contact Info" => 597
  ]
  14 => array:1 [
    "Contact Info" => 593
  ]
  15 => array:1 [
    "Contact Info" => 595
  ]
  16 => array:1 [
    "Contact Info" => 588
  ]
  17 => array:1 [
    "Contact Info" => 594
  ]
  18 => array:1 [
    "Contact Info" => 591
  ]
  19 => array:1 [
    "Contact Info" => 592
  ]
  20 => array:1 [
    "Contact Info" => 626
  ]
  21 => array:1 [
    "Contact Info" => 590
  ]
  22 => array:1 [
    "Address Info" => 85
  ]
  23 => array:1 [
    "Address Info" => 86
  ]
  24 => array:1 [
    "Address Info" => 87
  ]
  
]
```

i want the above like following array,note the array key will be dynamic not static one .can anyone please help me to acheive this one.

```
$temp = ['contact Info' => ['75','76',77',78'....] ,'Address Info' =. ['85','86','87'...]];
```

Comment: You must have tried something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case your keys are also dynamic you can try below code:

```
$temp = [];
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        foreach ($item as $key => $itemValue) {
            $temp[$key][] = $itemValue;
        }
    }

print_r($temp);
```

Hope it helps the `arrray_column()` solution is more efficient in case of not dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You can group these and to do unique and sort at finish.

```php
<?php


$data = [
    [
            "Contact Info" => 5
        ],
        [
            "Address Info" => 85
        ],
    [
            "Address Info" => 885
        ],
    [
            "Contact Info" => 592
        ],
    [
            "Address Info" => 85
        ],
    [
        "Address Info" => 8
        ],
    [
            "Contact Info" => 3
        ],
            [
            "Contact Info" => 3
        ],
    
    ];
$dumpData = ['Contact Info'=>array_unique(array_column($data,'Contact Info')),'Address Info'=> array_unique(array_column($data,'Address Info'))];
sort($dumpData['Contact Info']);
sort($dumpData['Address Info']);

echo'<pre>';

print_r($dumpData);
```

https://onlinephp.io/c/e6125